# table bottom border shown in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following html and CSS, which aims to put the wide column which is shown to desktop viewers, as a row underneath for any small screen devices. That much works. However, when I view it with Firefox (on a desktop browser), I get a border at the bottom of my table, but when I view it with Chrome I don't.

Please note that the border-bottom:0px; is necessary so that the two rows that are displayed on a small device in place of the single row on a large screen should not have a horizontal line between them.

As a simpler version of the problem, I have removed all the border attributes of the td completely, and only rely on the tbody border, and it still doesn't work. So clearly it is not the border-bottom:0px; attribute that is causing Chrome to omit the bottom line.

```css
.big-small-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.big-small-table th {
  border: thin solid;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
.big-small-table td {
/*border: thin solid;*/
/*border-bottom:0px;*/
/*border-top:0px;*/
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
.big-small-table tbody {
  border: thin solid;
}

.desc-big-screen {
  display:table-cell;
}

.desc-small-screen {
  display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 400px) {
  .desc-big-screen {
    display:none;
  }

  .desc-small-screen {
    display:table-cell;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<table class="big-small-table">
    <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th class="desc-big-screen">Description</th>
      <th>Data</th>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Small</td>
      <td class="desc-big-screen">This is the description of something small.</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" class="desc-small-screen">This is the description of something small.</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Medium</td>
      <td class="desc-big-screen">This is the description of something medium.</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" class="desc-small-screen">This is the description of something medium.</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Large</td>
      <td class="desc-big-screen">This is the description of something large.</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" class="desc-small-screen">This is the description of something large.</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>  
</body>
```

Does anyone know how I can make the border at the bottom of my table appear in Chrome as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved it by explicitly putting the border on all td's in the first row of each tbody in big screen mode and explicitly setting the same border to zero in little screen mode. It's ugly, but at least I now have a work-around for Chrome ignoring the tbody border at the bottom of the table!

```css
.big-small-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.big-small-table th {
  border: thin solid;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
.big-small-table td {
  border-left: thin solid;
  border-right: thin solid;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
.big-small-table tbody {
  border: thin solid;
}
.big-small-table tbody tr:first-child td {
  border-bottom: thin solid;
}
.desc-big-screen {
  display:table-cell;
}

.desc-small-screen {
  display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 400px) {
  .big-small-table tbody tr:first-child td {
    border-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .desc-big-screen {
    display:none;
  }

  .desc-small-screen {
    display:table-cell;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<table class="big-small-table">
    <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th class="desc-big-screen">Description</th>
      <th>Data</th>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Small</td>
      <td class="desc-big-screen">This is the description of something small.</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" class="desc-small-screen">This is the description of something small.</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Medium</td>
      <td class="desc-big-screen">This is the description of something medium.</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" class="desc-small-screen">This is the description of something medium.</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Large</td>
      <td class="desc-big-screen">This is the description of something large.</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" class="desc-small-screen">This is the description of something large.</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>  
</body>
```